# Adding devise_invitable gem into existing devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise for user authentication on my RoR web app, I also want to use "devise_invitable" gem to make invitations to friends. I follow the documentation but got an error when I click on "Send invitation email" button. [click to see devise_invatable gem](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable)

What I've done so far is:

1. Add devise_invitable gem
2. Add :invitable flag to the existing devise user model

devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

3. Add DeviseInvitable to my "users" table

   ```
   def change
   add_column :users, :invitation_token, :string
   add_column :users, :invitation_created_at, :datetime
   add_column :users, :invitation_sent_at, :datetime
   add_column :users, :invitation_accepted_at, :datetime
   add_column :users, :invitation_limit, :integer
   add_column :users, :invited_by_id, :integer
   add_column :users, :invited_by_type, :string
   add_index :users, :invitation_token, :unique => true

   change_column_null :users, :encrypted_password, :string, true
   ```

   end

The error message looks like this:

```
PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: null value in column "first_name" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (3, null, null, null, little@sheep.com, $2a$11$BcpZUt1rFlj85gdhj3F.ReTDOFNIy1FaV8cyco0gITa2TyQu7/oJy, null, null, null, 0, null, null, null, null, 2017-11-07 21:37:44.031886, 2017-11-07 21:37:44.031886, null, 4d51bd86a5cf613f64aaf0b1e0920f87441f04f7b62f4b3abcbee12ae061e806, 2017-11-07 21:37:44.030662, 2017-11-07 21:37:44.030662, null, null, 1, User). : INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at", "invitation_token", "invitation_created_at", "invitation_sent_at", "invited_by_id", "invited_by_type") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9) RETURNING "id"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your `schema.rb` table `users`.

You will see that it has a column `first_name` with the constraint `null:false`

This is your User that I retrieved from your log message

```
3, null, null, null, little@sheep.com, $2a$11$BcpZUt1rFlj85gdhj3F.ReTDOFNIy1FaV8cyco0gITa2TyQu7/oJy, null, null, null, 0, null, null, null, null, 2017-11-07 21:37:44.031886, 2017-11-07 21:37:44.031886, null, 4d51bd86a5cf613f64aaf0b1e0920f87441f04f7b62f4b3abcbee12ae061e806, 2017-11-07 21:37:44.030662, 2017-11-07 21:37:44.030662, null, null, 1, User
```

`3` is the user `id`, while one of those `null` values will be the `first_name`

with this gem you added columns to the `users` table, when you send an invitation you want to update that row by `inserting` the following details in the table

The `row` is the one with `id=3` so it already exists

```
INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at", "invitation_token", "invitation_created_at", "invitation_sent_at", "invited_by_id", "invited_by_type") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9) RETURNING "id"
```

When the db tries to save the changes the error is triggered, try to open the rails console with `rails c` and update that record.

```
user = User.find(3)
user.first_name = 'random name'
user.save
```

then try again with the same record

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I remove the null constraint in my database and it worked.